# Blue flash light (Arc) on Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-sensors

Is there any way to have access to the blue flash light appears on google map? I have read in different forums that this blue arc is representative of the reliability of the magnet sensor, is there any way to have access to it in android?

Comment: what blue flush light are you talking about

Comment: @SharartiKAKI there is a blue dot that indicates your location and recently there is a beam on the blue dot that will now also indicate your direction of movement. The beam get narrow and wide based on the reliability of magnet sensors, I wonder if there is a way to have access to that measure of reliability Google uses.  Below link may make my question more clear:
https://www.droid-life.com/2016/09/20/blue-dot-google-maps/

Comment: And this link :
https://support.google.com/maps/answer/2839911?hl=en&visit_id=636818354165789769-4268523419&rd=1&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1

Comment: have you solved the problem?

Comment: @SharartiKAKI No, I just mentioned the links in order to make my question more clear. It has not been solved yet.

Comment: ok, now tel me what you want

Comment: @SharartiKAKI 
Thanks. As we know the direction of movement estimation on Android is based on the magnet sensors. Android outputs the direction of movement with some measures of reliability(blue arc or blue beam on the screen). Google shows this measure of reliability with a blue beam( arc or flashlight) on the screen. The wider the beam is, the less reliable the output of the magnet sensor and consequently the direction of movement is. I need to have access to this measure of reliability google uses to show that beam on the screen.

Comment: I think by magnet you mean the GPS sensor right??

Comment: @SharartiKAKI Hi, I suppose that there is no GPS sensor, we have some GPS receiver antennas that are embedded in a cell phone. By the magnet( that can help to improve the accuracy of positioning based on GPS signals as well) I mean the defined parameters in below link in the sections:
TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD_UNCALIBRATED and TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position

Comment: ok I got it, dude can you share some code relevant to location setting. I want to see how you are getting location

Comment: What client are you using for location? Fused location api?

Comment: @SharartiKAKI Unfortunately we do not use the location services, our work is related to the indoor positioning system, where there is no GPS signal available. We developed an algorithm using inertial measurement units and some other transceivers, and we barely use the location system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went through Android SDK for magnet outputs. I have found one method that measure the accuracy of magnet based direction of movement. Have you seen following method?

```
@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {
    if(sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD){

    }
}
```

This outputs the accuracy in 4 levels for magnet based heading estimation.