# android googleMaps - how to make blue dot positional marker show users direction?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

if you check on googleMaps in android phone you will see that the users current position is shown with a blue dot but it also shows the direction the phone is pointing in.  [image]

look at this image, it shows that im holding the phone in a certain direction based on the spotlight.  How can i turn on this spot light in a googleMap for android. i have a map in my app but it does not show the spot light. How to turn it on ?

Comment: I don`t think it in api. look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984194/blue-flash-light-arc-on-google-maps

Comment: do you want to show user current location with a blue dot?

Comment: i want the spot light affect @pankaj yadav.  look at google maps when user turns the spot light also turns.

Comment: have you solved it

Comment: not yet. i dont have a need for it a this time but curious how it can be done.